# SSH into Raspberry Pi times out, ping can't reach host

Tags: ssh, static-ip

I've set up [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) to have a static IP address (raspberrypi.local).
For the time being I use an Ethernet cable for Raspberry Pi and Wi-Fi for Mac. Everything works fine connecting with my Mac:

```
ssh raspberrypi.local -l pi
```

Out of the blue, after eight hours more or less, I couldn't reach `raspberrypi` using ping nor ssh. I've cheched:

- My computer does not have a firewall
- Log in to SSH from the Raspberry Pi itself, `ssh 127.0.0.1 -OK`
- Ping to www.google.com from both sides is OK
- Restart Avahi daemon: `sudo /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon restart`
- [ifconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) confirms that I have set up the static IP correctly.

When I woke up today (after eight hours) it works again...curious.

Maybe it would be better to use the other approach for the static IP address (modifying the `/etc/network/interfaces` file).

Comment: Related question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/62932/55871

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no way to have avahi assigning you a static IP address (an IP address looks something like 192.168.0.23 for IPv4 or 2001:DB8:F001:BEEF::23 for IPv6).

What you are probably talking about is the domain name, avahi is announcing to the network (raspberrypi.local). This domain name is resolved (translated) somewhere in the network to an IP address, because this IP address is the number your net is using to deliver the IP packets to the target.

The translation *domain name => IP address* is usually done by a Domain Name System Server (DNS Server). There usually is no DNS Server in a simple home network. Sometimes your Wifi router is doing some DNS stuff. But in your case, you are doing the name resolving stuff with avahi.

**This is how avahi works:**

The avahi daemon on your RPi is choosing some link local IP address (say 169.254.0.1, you should see this in your ifconfig output, link local addresses are always beginning with 169.254) and then it is sendig messages through the net, announcing: 169.254.0.1 should now be called raspberrypi.local.

These kind of messages are received by other avahi daemons or by zeroconf daemons on Macs. zeroconf will write on it's list: 169.254.0.1 is now called raspberrypi.local.

If you type `ssh raspberrypi.local` on your Mac, zeroconf will replace raspberrypi.local with 169.254.0.1 and ssh is talking to the correct machine.

It could be, that your RPi is selecting another IP address after a few hours (maybe because nobody talks to it?). And it seems like your Mac is not listening to the annunciation of the new address because it is sleeping, or there is a communication problem between avahi and zeroconf.

**Solution:**

I would recommend, not to rely on avahi / zeroconf as it is not 100% predictable. I am assuming that your network consists of a router and some devices (at least Mac and RPi). The router is a wifi router where your Mac is connected via wifi and the RPi is connected via ethernet cable. With this network you somehow need to make sure that the IP address of your RPi is always the same. After that, you can somehow map the IP to a domain name.

At first the IP address: You most probably have a [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server in your wifi router (this is a standard functionality of home wifi routers). The DHCP server is assigning dynamic IP addresses to the devices in your network. But only to the devices asking for one. To allow all the devices in your network to talk to each other, they all are in the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). The subnet is most probably 192.168.0.0/24 or 192.168.1.0/24. This means, all addresses in your network are starting with 192.168.0. or 192.168.1. and only the part after the last point is changing. (Note: This is a different subnet than avahi and zeroconf are using. Every device can be in different subnets). To know the subnet, look at the first three parts of the IP address of your router, your Mac and/or your RPi.

To know where to reach your RPi from your Mac, you can do (for example) one of these four things:

1. **Setup a static IPv4 address on your RPi** in `/etc/network/interfaces` or in NetworkManager. This address should be outside the range of addresses, your DHCP server (in your Wifi router) is using so that no other device will get the same address, sometimes you can configure this range. But the address needs also to be within the subnet, your Mac is in. The `/etc/network/interfaces` would look like

   ```
   iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.23
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.1
   ```

   gateway would be the address of your router, netmask the same as here, address: the same as the address of your router but with a different number after the last point. Remove other sections starting with `iface eth0 inet`.
2. **Setup the DHCP server to assign always the same IP address to your RPi.** It will identify the RPi with its [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). You will have to enter it in the config interface of your router. You can find the RPi's MAC addres in the output of `ifconfig` look for a number like b8:27:eb:XX:XX:XX in the `eth0` section.
3. **Setup a static IPv6 address on your RPi and on your Mac.** This is my favorite option, as you don't have to care about DHCP ranges. But you will need a router that understands IPv6 and if you are using a switch, it needs to be a dumb link layer switch, or if it is a managed switch, it needs to understand IPv6.

   - Generate IPv6 Unique Local Address (ULA) with [this tool](https://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/) or make one up. It will look like fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::/48.
   - Add a number after the last colon (fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::23) and put it in your RPiS' `/etc/network/interfaces` file after the other stuff:

     ```
     iface eth0 inet6 static
       address fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::23
       netmask 64
     ```
   - Add another number after the last colon (fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::42) and configure that in your Mac. I don't know how as I am not a Mac user. But most probably there is a `/private/etc/network/interfaces` file, or you can add a IPv6 ULA via the Network configuration UI.
4. **Tell your network's router to assign a domain name to your RPi** (it will identify the RPi with its MAC address, assign a dynamic IP address via DHCP and resolve the domain name to this address). Not all routers have that functionality.

**Assign a name to the fixed IP address, you configured in points 1, 2 or 3:**

On your mac, you can add the ip address together with a name to your [`/private/etc/hosts` file](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/) like

```
192.168.1.23 raspberrypi.local
```

or for the IPv6 address:

```
fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::23 raspberrypi.local
```

This would be enough to use `raspberrypi.local` to talk to your RPi with different programs. To simplify your life further more with SSH, you can also create a SSH config file in your user directory in `USERDIR/.ssh/config`. For the IPv4 address it would look like

```
Host raspberrypi.local
  HostName 192.168.1.23
  Port 22
  User pi
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

or for the IPv6 address like

```
Host raspberrypi.local
  HostName fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::23
  AddressFamily inet6
  User pi
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

you can omit the `IdentityFile` lines. Those are pointing to your SSH key. But if you use it and add the content of your Macs`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to your RPi's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, you can ssh to you RPi without entering a username or password, just:

```
ssh raspberrypi.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem as you, I discovered that extensively `ping`-ing does bring up the wifi-connection again. I observed that after the 70-100th ping the *Pi* starts responding and after that an `ssh`-connection can be initiated successfully.

**Edit** Turn power save off

```
iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

Click here for [details](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/97864/22174).